# How to fire dropdowclosed event of combobox in WPF programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox that fires an event when dropdown is closed. How do raise dropdownclosed event of combobox programmatically?

I was trying this code:

```
MainWindow.ComboBoxTemplates.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ComboBox.DropDownClosedEvent));
```

but seems that doesn't work.

Comment: DropDownClosed is not a routed event, it's a common CLR event. You can't force it unless the invocator is protected. Only the event source i.e. the class that declares the event delegate can raise a CLR event. The event delegate invocator is generated as private.  Making it public would violate the encapsulation rules. Hence, you are trying to violate encapsulation, which indicates that you are doing something wrong. You should revisit your design.

Comment: You can .invoke an event, passing parameters for sender and event args. That just fires any subscribed event handlers though. You could define a method containing your logic used by an event handler and call just that method directly. None of this closes the drop-down though, if that's your purpose. An example handler would look like void OnDropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @Andy true. that was exacly what i did after this post. but i was interested is it possible to fire dropdownclosed event programmatically. any way ty for responce

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this code:

```
// Programmatically raise the DropDownClosed event
comboBox1.OnDropDownClosed(EventArgs.Empty);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can raise the DropDownClosed event of a ComboBox programmatically by calling the ComboBox.OnDropDownClosed method. Here's an example:

```
MainWindow.ComboBoxTemplates.OnDropDownClosed(new EventArgs());
```

This will raise the DropDownClosed event of the ComboBox named ComboBoxTemplates that is contained in the MainWindow.

Note that the ComboBox must be initialized before you can raise the DropDownClosed event. If the ComboBox has not been initialized, you will need to do so before calling the OnDropDownClosed method.